# Watin - Watin.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotFoundException

Tags: input, watin

I have code that runs that gives me the error : Could not find a 'INPUT (text password textarea hidden) or TEXTAREA' tag containing attribute name with value ____________ (It's testing a website)

It says it can't find a

What reason could it be that it can't find it? It finds others without an issue on other pages, but this page for some odd reason it baulks? How can that be?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but only on one computer. I use WatiN for web scraping. It works perfectly on my dev computer, my test computer, and 12 customer computers. It refuses to work on one customer computer.

Answer (score -1):

The WatiN codebase isn't that complex. Download it and run it in debug mode and see where it breaks when the exception is thrown, then you can examine the context surrounding the error.

Comment: Ok i guess i don't really know what good it will do. my code simply looks for an element that i gather and it can't find it,
pageFormElements = order.SelectSingleNode("/order/page[@name=\"" + ie.Uri.AbsolutePath + "\"]").SelectDescendants(XPathNodeType.Element, false);
But then when I loop through this element isn't there, but I can (rclick)view source and see the element there? This works on other pages just don't this one?